# How to Updgrade MySql for EF core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My Original projects.json file is like following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191",
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta902",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"

  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

These settings work with my MySql database.
I wanted to upgrade EF core to 1.1 so that I could use Update() method in my repository like following (this is nice-one line code and I do not need to assign each attribute incoming object to original object):

```
  public void UpdateBook(long id, Book book)
  {  
     var originalBook=  _db.Books.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
     _db.Entry(originalBook).CurrentValues.SetValues(book);
     _db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

However, when I upgraded EF core to 1.1 `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"` my code started throwing error in startup.cs at these lines:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
services.AddDbContext<WebAPIDataContext>(options =>
     {
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SampleConnection"));
            });
```

My guess is upgrading EF Core broke some dependency with MySql. Is it correct? How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**:

I removed `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"` and `"MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191"` and replaced with `"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "6.10.1-beta"`. In my aspsettings.josn I have:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SampleConnection": "server=localhost;userid=root;pwd=root;port=3306;database=aspnet;sslmode=none;"
  },
```

After restoring packages I restarted visual studio and build the solution which threw me following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
"MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191",
"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31",
```

Both are outdated and Oracle fucked up versioning. See [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/).

The IR31 was the last version to support EF Core 1.0. IR-191 is even older and one of the `6.*` was the first one to support EF Core 1.1.

Now there is again `7.0.7-m6` which also seems to support EF Core 1.1. Oracle seems to be playing rope skipping with the versions.

Either of the later two versions should work `6.10.1-beta` or `7.0.7-m6`.

Comment: To make sure which version should I use for which one? I mean which for `MySql.Data.Core` and which one for `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: You have to post the exact message. And of course also update `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",` to `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0" (or just remove it, as the Mysql provider has a dependency on it anyways)

Comment: It's a different issue now. You may need to update the according dependencies too, since EF Core 1.1 depends on some of the newer versions. You may leave ASP.NET Core to 1.0, but can update that too to 1.1 to gain access to the newer features added with it. It's up to you